# Run assetlibrary code without needing to use current location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, assetslibrary

When i run the following code:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library assetForURL:albumCopy
                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
                    ...
                 }
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                    ...
                }];
        [library autorelease];
```

the app asks the user for permission to use their current location. I don't use their current location in any way, so is there a way to stop it from asking the user? I know those messages always detract from the user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats not possible, Apple did this because the EXIF data of the photos contains the location and they don't have a way to request everything but the location tag from the photos. File a bug report, maybe they will implement something like this in a future iOS version.